# updateSwitchAtIndexPath crashes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I', have a UITableView with UISwitch in some cells.

I want to capture events, but it crashes when I try to add the indexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 //Create cell with all data

    UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


- (void)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   UISwitch *switchView = (UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView;

   if ([switchView isOn]) {
       NSLog(@"ON");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"OFF");
   }

}
```

It crashes, I think because I'm not adding the indexPath parameter, but I can't get how to set it.

```
 -[ParkingData updateSwitchAtIndexPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b88eb0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 //Create cell with all data

    UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


- (void)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(UISwitch *)switchview {
   if ([switchView isOn]) {
       NSLog(@"ON");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"OFF");
   }

}
```

Comment: yes! that works!!!! but, if I have not the indexPath, how can I know which is the row which is clicked?

Comment: @user1256477 you can set the tag of you UISwitch

Answer (score 1):

```
[switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

should be

```
[switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

you are missing just a colon. because your method has parameter.

```
- (void)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I have already tried this before, but it didnt work: -[UISwitch row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x797c400, could it be because is a grouped UITable?

Comment: make sure you declared this `- (void)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  in your header (.h)

Comment: It is declared, I also checked this before askingç

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean, No visible @interface for 'ParkingData' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents:'

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(id)sender
{
   // see the line BELOW
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[(UITableView*)[sender superview] superview]indexPathForCell: (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview]];

    if ([sender isOn])
        NSLog(@"ON");
    else
        NSLog(@"OFF");
}
```

In the above code sender means UISwitch and if u want indexPath of cell then the marked line helps to you.